# List private property names of the class

Tags: typescript, private, keyof

I need to use some subset of class properties names as values in a map to use inside of the class. In following example I've replaced map by array. The problem is that if property is marked `private` it's not listed in `keyof` list. **How can I specify type of keys if I need to include private names?**

```
var keys: Array<keyof A> = ["x", "y"]; // Error

class A {
  private x = 7;
  public y = 8;

  private keys: Array<keyof A> = ["x", "y"]; // Error
}
```

There is the same error both for variable outside of the class and for private property inside of it:

> Type '"x"' is not assignable to type '"y"'.

Comment: `private` and `protected` properties are hard to deal with programmatically since, as you noticed, they don't appear in `keyof`.  You might consider not making `x` private at all, and instead export a version of `A` that omits `x`. But that depends on your use case, which I don't know.

Comment: Compare [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAFATgSwG4gC7SQG8AoJJCADxgHs1cl4AbEKKJAQSNLKRkx3xIKALiRRcmYAHMkAXiQAiEAoDc3MjACuAI0YZ4SAJ6jgmsNoho5SAIxqevfnmQBrCIaij2aNCEMAeN0NqADMOAD5rAG0FCgUAGkVDBQBdFSQAegykAFEfWm4AX24cKyDPDh8-QPdQiOjYhKTU9Kzc-LRiYvhqYHFHbGdOeWAIAHdUJ3woADp2AAoASjU+Qfx2GcNW7NNzS2JVgQgNim3yDtEMXAByNkPnA6njmfKzyzRaS5u7p+JiIA)...

Comment: ...to [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEA5A9gFwKIA8ZoCcMIATJAbwCgkl4AbEKKJAfQEELqakcAuJKBgIBLYAHMkAXiQAiEDIDcXGgE9+wAK5gARhAJSkARiXckAawgqo-NgQIgVAHgsq0AM1ZsAfAYDaMnBkAGlkVGQBdBSQAemikNDMHLgBfLgg8QgwkUWICNwRkDnTiYBJmAHkwYQxHdhCAmSQAH1kXKBkfclSadPwiWjRgQSQ2dQgAdyQACgBKKR8OaXYTJAA3EH02mzsHZ0t3Tx9pf0D6sMiYuISk1Mp4QeHgTFw+4hJFpGAJ1GeMolIAHRsWZKJ7YP5vNgAlRRWKfLS6AiUMEvTKkKE4WFxPQEQj8GC4mB6DAqJAkNDQT6YJDpYSCZG-V7ogFtLE0ux4pAEtBEoik8mUsE0nB0jBAA).  Does that meet your needs?  If so I'll make an answer; otherwise the answer is probably just "no you can't do this, sorry"

Comment: @jcalz, interesting idea. I think you can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you noticed, `private` and `protected` properties of a class `C` do not appear as part of `keyof C`.  This is usually desirable behavior, since most attempts to index into a class with a private/protected property will cause a compile error.  There is a suggestion at [microsoft/TypeScript#22677](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22677) to allow [mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) a type to a version where the private/protected properties are public, which would give you a way to do this... but this feature has not been implemented as of TypeScript 4.9.

So this doesn't work:

```
namespace Privates {
  export class A {
    private x: string = "a";
    public y: number = 1;
    private keys: Array<keyof A> = ["x", "y"]; // Error
  }
  var keys: Array<keyof A> = ["x", "y"]; // Error
}
const privateA = new Privates.A();
privateA.y; // number
privateA.x; // error: it's private
privateA.keys; // error: it's private
```

But maybe you don't actually need the properties to be `private`, so much as not visible to outside users of the class.  You can use a module/namespace to export only the facets of your class that you want, like this:

```
namespace NotExported {
  class _A {
    x: string = "a";
    y: number = 1;
    keys: Array<keyof _A> = ["x", "y"]; // okay
  }
  export interface A extends Omit<_A, "x" | "keys"> {}
  export const A: new () => A = _A;
  var keys: Array<keyof _A> = ["x", "y"]; // okay
}

const notExportedA = new NotExported.A();
notExportedA.y; // number
notExportedA.x; // error: property does not exist
notExportedA.keys; // error: property does not exist
```

In `NotExported`, the class constructor `_A` and the corresponding type `_A` are not directly exported.  Internally, `keyof _A` contains both the `"x"` and `"y"` keys.  What we do export is a constructor `A` and a corresponding type `A` that omits the `x` property (and `keys` property) from `_A`.  So you get the internal behavior you desire, while the external behavior of `NotExported.A` is similar to that of `Privates.A`.  Instead of `x` and `keys` being inaccessible due to `private` violation, they are inaccessible because they are not part of the exported `A` type.

I actually prefer the latter method of not exporting implementation details rather than exposing the existence of `private` properties, since `private` properties actually have a lot of impact on how the corresponding classes can be used.  That is, `private` is about access control, not about encapsulation.

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAFATgSwG4gC7SQG8AoJJCADxgHs1cl4AbEKKJAQSNLKRkx3xIKALiRRcmYAHMkAXiQAiEAoDc3MjACuAI0YZ4SAJ6jgmsNoho5SAIxqevfnmQBrCIaij2aNCEMAeN0NqADMOAD5rAG0FCgUAGkVDBQBdFSQAegykAFEfWm4AX24cKyDPDh8-QPdQiOjYhKTU9Kzc-LRiYvhqYHFHbGdOeWAIAHdUJ3woADp2AAoASjU+Qfx2GcNW7NNzS2JVgQgNim3yDtEMXAByNkPnA6njmfKzyzRaS5u7p+JiLKyf1AkFgCGQADlqLgclRaPgACZcMhMFhsAD6nBIDhEYgkGGk1iUqnURhMZgsVnkdhJ5S8VQCQTqGMi8hicUSCmSaUy2WoLj8RW4lBodCQ+PwaBCYI45Ao+GA8LYAHkwFd-BiOXEkAAfRTlBSRQjFMjCuEMXr9dgmcZIJZySLDJAY+xIUpIWmVXwM2phZkNdnNbltPkC4rEHp9ejAKEwkUIx2jCaQ6GwugQeFzJZqaMpuPpjZbHlIXYU4g52Nw-MzU5F96fRzUGCWXCGJDw6gEHOyjDiMsx1Pxl7uKBvC4Npt0VvtztQ7viIA)

Comment: I want to create a Record<SomeEnumOrUnion, keyof this> inside a class to map the enum value to private methods to avoid long switch-case. What are the alternatives here?

Comment: If you have a separate/follow-up question, the comments section of a years-old answer isn't the best place to ask it.  Assuming you can't find the answer anywhere else, you might want to post your own question, with a full [mre] of the situation you're talking about.  That way you'll get more eyes on it than just mine, and you'll have the room to present your question in full.  Good luck!