# Move private field name to generic helper

Tags: typescript, private, mobx

Consider following code: [palyground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8CwAoa0AOAnAlgNzABcBTaAL2gF5oAGVAX1VUIE8NSBpK6AIjJ+ZtSANTAgcAEw7EWMarADaHALrRiADxIA7CTDBaW0APzQuALmhbieYllRA)

```
class A {
  private z = 0
}

type K = "z"
type ValidKeys = A[K] extends any ? K : never
```

Type `ValidKeys` compiles fine and becomes the same as `K` only if `K` is some subset of keys of `A`. And doesn't compile if I try to add anything else to `K` like

```
type K = "z" | "not-a-key"
```

That's exactly the behavior that I need, but I want to make `ValidKeys` generic depending on `A` and `K`:

```
type ValidKeys<A, K> = ...
```

**How can I make such type?**

---

#### Why do I need it?

I'm using mobx and its [documentation says](https://mobx.js.org/observable-state.html#limitations):

> 8. By default *TypeScript* will not allow you to annotate private fields. This can be overcome by explicitly passing the relevant private fields as generic argument, like this: `makeObservable<MyStore, "privateField" | "privateField2">(this, { privateField: observable, privateField2: observable })`

So I need to pass a type containing some private keys to generic function. If I just pass a literal, code will compile after renaming the property and will break at runtime.

So instead of

```
constructor() {
  makeObservable<Store, "x" | "y">(this, { x: observable, y: false })
}
```

I want to write

```
constructor() {
  makeObservable<Store, ValidKeys<Store, "x" | "y">>(this, { x: observable, y: false })
}
```

so that it would break at compile-time if the key is renamed.

The only way I found is explicitly write a snippet inside of my constructor:

```
constructor() {
  type ExtraKeys = "x" | "y"
  type _CompilesIfOk_ExtraKeys = Store[ExtraKeys]
  makeObservable<Store, ExtraKeys>(this, { x: observable, y: false })
}
```

And want to simplify it and move into some helper.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible right now because [private members are not enumerable in `keyof`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57066049/list-private-property-names-of-the-class). And this is exactly why MobX asking you for the keys, because if it was possible then MobX could just check it by itself (like it does with non-private fields).

Yes, it breaks type safety, but nothing you can do about it at this moment (in a generic way).

There is a discussion about that topic on Github: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22677

Comment: Oh.. I hoped there is some hack for that... Note that I'm asking not to get all private keys, but only to verify whether specified key exists.

Comment: This is basically the same problem. If you could verify that the key exists then you could list them and vice-versa.

Comment: Actually not. My solution in the question does verification, but can't be used to get the keys.